# How to shade in the range slider in plotly for python

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I am trying to shade in the range slider for my plotly chart in python I have went through the documentation and I am not finding what I am after. I am attaching my plotly code along with the chart I am currently using and the example chart I wish to mimick.

```
# Plotly Express Line Chart
blue = dict(color='blue', width=2)
green = dict(color='green', width=2)

trace1 = go.Scatter(x=df['maturityDate'], y=df['EXAMPLE.DF'], mode='lines', line=blue,
                   name='EXAMPLE.DF')

trace2 = go.Scatter(x=df['maturityDate'], y=df['EXAMPLECLIENT.DF'], mode='lines', line=green,
                   name='EXAMPLECLIENT.DF')

layout = go.Layout(autosize=True,
                   xaxis=dict(type='date',
                              tickformat="%b %Y",
                              dtick='M6',
                              automargin=True,
                              showgrid=True,
                              gridcolor='#dddddd',
                              title='Time',
                              gridwidth=0.3,
                              rangeslider=dict(visible=True,
                                               thickness=0.05,
                                               bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0.1)',
                                               bordercolor='rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
                                               borderwidth=1)
                              ),
                   yaxis=dict(title='DF (%)',
                              showgrid=True,
                              gridcolor='#dddddd',
                              gridwidth=0.3,
                              tickformat=".2%",
                              dtick = 0.02),
                   legend=dict(x=0.5,
                               y=1.02,
                               orientation='h',
                               traceorder='normal',
                               font=dict(size=14),
                               yanchor='middle',
                               xanchor='center'),
                   plot_bgcolor='white',
                   paper_bgcolor='white')

fig = go.Figure(data=[trace1, trace2], layout=layout)
fig.update_layout(title= dict(text = f"DF Curve Comparison::{adate_input[0]:%Y-%m-%d}",
                                  font=dict(size=24,
                                            family='bold'),
                                  x=0.5,
                                  xanchor='center'))
```

Wrong image
[image]

Here is a example of what I hope to achieve notice the shaded in range bar.

[image]